# Is shaving Siberian Huskies harmful?

Tags: hair, dogs

I recently came across [a post on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvII9.jpg) claiming shaving a Siberian husky exposes it to "sunburn, skin cancer, insects, and parasites".

[image: Example of claim]

> [...] the layers of your pet's coat help to protect them from overheating and sunburn.

The [claim seems to be quite well spread](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=don%27t%20shave%20huskies). However I can't seem to find any sources that verify the claim. All sources I can find seem to be enthusiast sites which I feel might be rife with myths and hearsay.

Does shaving huskies expose them to sunburn and overheating?

Comment: I would normally consider a post on imgur.com to not qualify as notable, but this claim seems plausible, and your Google link supports the notability; could you include some of those links from the search results directly in your post? Also, not to say that Skeptics is not a good place for this question (I do think it's on-topic), but a better place might be [pets.se] or possibly [biology.se]. Anyway, good question.\

Comment: I was going to editing this to "shearing", but [decided to check first](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255205/does-one-shave-or-shear-a-dog).

Comment: Are they talking about shaving down to the skin, or just cutting the fur so that it's thinner/shorter? I've heard the word used both ways for dogs in particular.

Comment: They are talking about trimming/clipping/shearing, not shaving. See the link in my above comment and the pictures shown in imgur.

Comment: @Oddthinking that English question went hot, and an answer led me to ask http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/do-yaks-get-shaved , without realising your ELU question was based on a Skeptics question.

Comment: @Andrew: Ha. It's all very recursive.

Comment: @Oddthinking Wow, I was reading it as shearing and didn't even register! ...I should get more sleep.